# How to compute the throughput varying the bandwidth

Tags: wireless, wifi, capacity

Let's say that I have two different wireless technologies, A and B.

A has a bandwidth of BA MHz, B has a bandwidth of BB MHz. I can compute the capacity of (for instance A) with Shannon:

```
CA = BA * log(1 + SNR)
```

but what if A is on frequency band FA, and B on FB? If, for instance, B is on a higher bandwidth, the total amount of information that B can transfer would be higher compared to A. How could be possible to compute this? I'd like to compute this regardless of the technology, whether FEC is implied or not etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The center frequency of the band does not matter. A 1 MHz band around 5 MHz carries as much information as a 1 MHz band around 1 GHz.

Comment: Ok, but on the same unit time, at 10 GHz i can send much more information than, for instance, 1 GHz. Am I right?

Comment: Only if you  increase the bandwidth B in Shannon's formula.

Comment: Yes, but let's take an example: Wifi on 5 GHz have a much higher throughput compared to standard 2.4 GHz. This is because on the same unit time, you can transmit more information due to the higher frequency.

Comment: You're missing the point.  Information capacity depends only on bandwidth, not center frequency (note the absence of center frequency in Shannon's formula). The only advantage of using higher center frequencies is that there is more available bandwidth. For example, if you have an information bandwidth of 100 MHz, then you could barely transmit it with a center frequency of 100 MHz.  With a center frequency of 200 MHz, it would be much easier.

Comment: @lbedogni, I don't know the wifi standards, but it sounds like the 5 GHz standard uses either a wider bandwidth, or has better SNR, or uses an ecoding scheme that allows it to achieve closer to the Shannon limit. In your original question, you specified that the B term is a given of the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify few points about WiFi at 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz: First, on 2.4 GHz, the channels are overlapping, with the result of sharing channel with other users and users on neighboring channels being interference. The 2.4 GHz 802.11b uses less efficient modulation than 5 GHz 802.11a, but that isn't related to frequency. The 2.4 GHz 802.11g and 5 GHz 802.11a, which have similar modulation, have same data rate.

Comment: In 802.11n, which uses both bands, 5 GHz may be faster than 2.4 only because of what I mentioned at the beginning of the comment. For example, it's easier to use wider channels in 5 GHz band, due to less crowding than in it in 2.4 GHz band, but that doesn't have anything to do with frequency itself, just its uses. In 802.11ac, then 2.4 GHz band has been completely abandoned, mainly because it's crowded and the allocation is too small, so very wide channels used there wouldn't fit the allocation.

Comment: Maybe I badly explained myself. What I mean is that, on the same amount of time, a signal at frequency F transmit the double of waves of a signal at frequency F/2. So, basically, one can "stuff" more information in this, and achieve a higher datarate. Is this correct or am I missing the point? I know that for Shannon capacity this does not matter, I'm just speaking about the throughput that one can achieve.